# HTML page quote outer jquery file does not work

Tags: jquery

I make a html page in eclipse, but **it does not work when I quote the outer jquery file**.
Below is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/layout.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../css/flexigrid.css">
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="../script/flexigrid.js"></script>
<title>Insert title here</title>
<script charset="UTF-8">
$(document).ready(function(){
//  document.getElementById("data").style.display="block";
    $("data").css("display", "block");
}); 
</script>
</head>
<body">
<table id="data" style="width:200px; border:solid red 1px; display:none; ">
    <tr>
        <td>jnoifsf</td>
        <td>nifs</td>
        <td>nofsfsa</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>mflsf</td>
        <td>noijfs</td>
        <td>mifsf</td>
    </tr>
</table> 
</body>
</html>
```

**The annotated code of line 12 can work.**

Comment: By outer jQuery file, do you mean the importation of the file?

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
$('#data').css("display", "block");
```

Or even easier:

```
$('#data').show();
```